# Jitter units for Live555

Tags: live555, qos, jitter

I am going through some documentation of a voip software that uses Live555 as the underlying network layer. As per [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) for RTSP - live555 seems to have implemented it. But the output is not clear to me. From archives of Live555 [here](http://live-devel.live555.narkive.com/Hml9JDzJ/jitter-value-with-openrtsp)  question it seems that to get jitters in terms of mirco or milli seconds, I have to divide the jitter value by sampling frequency. But what about the network bit-rate? Should I use it to divide the jitter value to derive jitter in terms of micro/milliseconds?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Output is not clear in what sense ? Please be elaborate. Is it getting stuck? Is there a visible frame loss?

Comment: The voip application displays jitter values but does not provide units, So I checked the code and found out that I need to divide the jitter values by sampling rates. Jitter values are for Video and Audio streams separately, I want to know if I divide the jitter value for each stream by network-bitrate or sampling rate of audio and video.

Comment: I think you should be dividing it by the network-bitrate because that is the final link in  the chain. Your app basically displays the jitter you get whence the RTSP packets have traversed the network and will, in-effect also contain pre-packet encapsulation jitter values. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of the same but still unsure about this. May be I will dig it out somehow.