# Convert Jitter from RTP timestamp unit to millisseconds

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, jitter, rtcp

I have a video conference app and I want to display the Interarrival Jitter to the user. I am getting this information from FFmpeg, and it follows the [RFC 3550 Appendix A.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#appendix-A.8), so the information is in timestamp units. I am not sure how to convert it. I am currently dividing the Jitter by 90.000 (the video stream timebase). Is this correct?

Similar question: [Jitter units for Live555](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149406/jitter-units-for-live555)

Comment: `(timestamp / 90000) * 1000` for milliseconds.

Comment: @Gyan Awesome! I forgot to mention the *1000 to go from seconds to ms, I am already doing that. It's just a confirmation that I was doing right, but I was insecure and you seem to know about this (by your profile). Why you didn't post as answer? Because you think an answer should be more in-depth? Well, thank you anyway